# Call public void and private string methods with return value

Tags: c#, winforms

In my application I want to have my main form(Form1) call a method on my UserControl(EmailControl). Below are the three main methods I am wanting to call:

```
public void InitializeConnection(string hostname, int port)
    {
        try
        {
            _imapClient = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
            _imapNs = _imapClient.GetStream();
            _imapSw = new StreamWriter(_imapNs);
            _imapSr = new StreamReader(_imapNs);

            label1.Text = "*** Connected ***";
            Response();
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

,

```
    public void AuthenticateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        _imapSw.WriteLine("$ LOGIN " + username + " " + password);
        _imapSw.Flush();
        label2.Text = "Logged in";
        Response();
    }
```

and

```
    public string MailCount()
    {
        _imapSw.WriteLine("$ STATUS INBOX (messages)");
        _imapSw.Flush();

        string res = Response();
        Match m = Regex.Match(res, "[0-9]*[0-9]");
        return m.ToString();
    }
```

To do this, I am using this on the usercontrol page:

```
    Form1.getemail += new Form1.sendtoemail(this.sendover);
```

and

```
    public void sendover()
    {
        InitializeConnection("hostname", 123);
        AuthenticateUser("username", "password");
        MailCount();
    }
```

Then on my main page I have

```
public delegate void sendtoemail(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event sendtoemail getemail;
```

and

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.getemail != null) 
        {
            this.getemail(this, e);

        }
    }
```

After doing this, on my usercontrol page it is telling me that there is no overload for "sendover" matches delegate "sendtoemail", and that I need an object reference. What exactly is throwing the error?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like WinForms...

Comment: Sorry, will change that now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `getemail` event is of type `sendtoemail`, so the function you add as a handler must match that signature.

Here are two solutions:

Change

```
public void sendover()
```

to

```
public void sendover(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

or change

```
Form1.getemail += new Form1.sendtoemail(this.sendover);
```

to

```
Form1.getemail += (s, e) => sendover();
```

The first solution changes the signature of sendover to match the delegate type, and the second solution creates an anonymous function with the correct type which calls sendover.

Comment: Awesome, so that fixed one error... However, it still has `Form1.getemail` underlined and says "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.getemail'.

Comment: That means that Form1 is the type of your form, not the instance of your form.

Answer (score 2):

Your method `sendover` doesn't respect the `sendtoemail` delegate's method signature:

```
public delegate void sendtoemail(object sender, EventArgs e); // accepts 2 parameters
```

Instead of the method declaration:

```
public void sendover() { // ...
```

... declare it as...

```
public void sendover(object sender, EventArgs e) { // ...
```